# Simple C program won't compile- error is "dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for architecture i386"

Tags: c, gcc

MacOS Catalina 10.15.3
2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7

I'm following along with a computer science textbook, and trying to compile a simple program to assembly language so I can see what's happening under-the-hood.  I'm doing so using a 32-bit architecture, since that's what the text uses for its compilation (it's an old book), but I'm running this on a 64-bit machine.  Since I'm just asking the compiler to output a file (not to run it), I wouldn't expect this to be a problem.

I have the following program, in a file named `sum.c`:

```
int accum = 0;

int sum(int x, int y) {
  int val = x + y;
  accum += val;
  return val;
}

int main() {
  return sum(3,2);
}
```

I'm trying to compile it down to assembly using the following command in my terminal:

```
gcc -m32 -O1 -o sum sum.c
```

Instead of the expected `sum` output file, I see the following error:

```
ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, missing required architecture i386 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
ld: dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

From what I can tell, the compiler is ignoring the file `libSystem.tbd` because that file requires a 32-bit architecture, and then the linker subsequently fails because that file is missing from the compilation.

I'd love to be able to follow along with the examples in the text, but I'm not sure what options I have other than switching to a 32-bit machine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well, [just use godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/exG7z4)

Comment: Consider using [Debian](http://debian.org/), and read the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). You want to compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Why don't you use a 64 bits compiler? Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and take inspiration from *existing* software on [github](https://github.com/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the text I'm using as a reference uses a 32-bit architecture in its example code.

Comment: If you just want to see the assembly language, how about `gcc -m32 -O1 -S sum.c`?  That will compile the the C source to assembly output in `sum.s`.

Comment: @IanAbbott that must be it, I was missing the `-S` flag.  Not sure how that happened, but thank you!

Comment: Better use  `gcc -m32 -O2 -S -Wall -fverbose-asm sum.c` assuming a recent and genuine  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Strangely, I'd never heard of the `-fverbose-asm` option before. It sounds useful!